# Translate anonymous function

Tags: c#, lambda

If you have function with parameter of this type `Func<bool,bool>` I know that this can be a function that has one parameter of type `bool` and returns a `bool` too.

I saw that people pass here lambda like this : `(x => x)` , what does it mean? How can it be translated to a normal function?

Comment: `...but I saw that people pass here`. Can you show some examples.

Comment: And someday you'll see `Func<bool> fn = () => true` :-)

Comment: @xanatos: That is very `true`.

Comment: @xanatos and what does it mean ? Action<bool> function with no parameters which returns always true ?

Comment: @kosnkov No, `Func<bool>` with no parameters that always returns `true`  :-) And this `Func<int> fn = () => 9` is the random number generator of Dilbert: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 (at least from the point of view of Dilbert)

Comment: @kosnkov: An `Action` doesn't return anything. That is a method that doesn't take any parameters, and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be compared to this regular method:

```
public bool SomeMethod(bool x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Effectively it is returning the same variable that was provided to the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the lambda expression [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) docs it says:

> the lambda expression **x => x * x** specifies a parameter that’s named x
>   and returns the value of x squared. You can assign this expression to
>   a delegate type.

To convert it into normal function you can write it as:

```
public bool MethodName(bool x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Func<bool,bool>
      |    |
    input  |
        output
```

Is equivalent to

```
public bool Foo(bool bar)
{
    return bar; // do something with bar
}
```

---

You can also have many input parameters, e.g.

```
Func<bool, bool, bool>
     |      |     |
  input1  input2  |
               output
```

Is equivalent to

```
public bool Foo(bool foo, bool bar)
{
    return foo && bar; // do something with foo and bar
}
```

---

And if your output is just `void`, you can use an `Action<T>`

```
Action<bool, bool, bool>
       |      |     |
  input1  input2 input3
```

Is equivalent to

```
public void Foo(bool foo, bool bar, bool foobar)
{
    this.result = foo && bar && foobar; // do something with foo and bar and foobar
    // ouch! no return because it's a void
}
```